# Veracode as a precommit hook for git

Tags: code-coverage, webhooks, pre-commit-hook, veracode

How to integrate Veracode scanner as a pre-commit hook for git working repository? How can we check weather the scanner is actually running?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a GitHub Action about Veracode static scan analysis. To do this you can follow the steps below:

1. In the Security tab of your GitHub project (you need to have admin rights for the GitHub project), click on "Enable settings" for "Code
   scanning alerts".
2. This takes you to the Settings of the project, where you need to “Enable” “GitHub Advanced Security” for “Code scanning”,
3. and then click the “Go to code scanning” button that will be enabled.
4. Scrolling down on the list appearing with multiple code scanning tools, you pick “Veracode Static Analysis” (usually appearing on the bottom of the page).
5. Clicking to “Set up this workflow”, automatically creates a subdirectory in master branch in .github/workflows path. The workflow is configured in a .yml file, that contains the steps of the pipeline.
6. Prerequisite: you need to set up Veracode API Keys as Project Secrets (have a look here [Create Veracode API keys](https://help.veracode.com/r/t_create_api_creds) and here
   [setup GitHub Action Secrets for Repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository). Name your API Keys as VERACODE_API_ID and VERACODE_API_KEY (as these are the names that are set in .yml file or change them accordingly in both locations)
7. In the .yml file that got created automatically there is a pipeline that runs according to the rules set on the line where it says
   [image: check the image]

you can have a look at this link for more information [on push/pull request branches/tags](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags)
[image]
branch names can be altered, following regular expressions as well, see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet) for more info.

8. You can configure the Action to run on schedule as well.
   Hover over “cron” to see the man-read format that appears. With this, the Action will run according to cron. Scheduled workflows run on the latest commit on the default or base branch.
   Find more information on how to configure scheduled events on GitHub Actions [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events)
9. In the Actions tab of your Project you can now see the logs of the run of the pipeline and each run's status.
10. After you have set up the GitHub Action as described above (steps 1-8), and the Action has run well (check its status as described in step 9) in the Security tab of your GitHub project, you should be able to see that "Code scanning alerts" are "Active", click on "View alerts", that takes you to the list of the Veracode flaws if any.

Comment: Do we have the same option In Bitbucket? I can not see any code scanning Aviable in Bitbucket .

Comment: I found this link regarding bitbucket, https://help.veracode.com/r/yWEmzLVoSzK6HlP~GSch2w/FSgrksCEoCCYFufkmrcYww